# No traffic getting captured towards UTM's except "Google" and "Firebase"

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics-firebase, utm-tracking

I am having a tough time while analysing store listing for my app with third party referrals. When i am analysing UTM sources under Store analysis in play console I don't see any visitor/ acquisition towards most of my UTM sources except few like "Firebase", "Google", "Other", "Undefined".
There used to be data for other UTM's(Our website, our desktop app) as well in past but not anymore. I wonder what went wrong, it might be possible that these UTM's are tracked under Other category somehow.

We don't have any api call in app to send related events to firebase, are we missing something here, may be install referral api? may be some other api mentioned here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns, but we never had anything extra apart from setting up firebase in our project, I followed https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.

Is it necessary to send data to google analytics in my case like mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/mobile-campaign-deep-link#campaign-tracking, I don't feel it is right as firebase anyways tracking 'visitors' without hitting any app code.

Any suggestion on how to debug it?